# Why should i type six times rather than twice

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

i am trying to type some alphabet into two different arrs and then print some result message ,but i have to type 6 times and my result is the last twice

```
    String str1[] =new String[100];
    String str2[]=new String[100];
    int count=0;
    while(true) {
        Scanner s1=new Scanner(System.in);
        if(s1.nextLine()=="END") {
            break;
        }
        str1[count]=s1.nextLine();
        Scanner s2=new Scanner(System.in);
        if(s2.nextLine()=="END") {
            break;
        }
        str2[count]=s2.nextLine();
        count++;
        System.out.println("完成第" + count + "个依赖" + "  " + s1.nextLine() +  "->" + s2.nextLine());
    }
```

Comment: First, never compare `String`s using `==`. Always use `equals()`. Second, instantiating multiple `Scanner` objects at the same time will likely cause issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `nextLine` you get a new line (that's why you must type everything so many times, you aren't saving the values you get). Compare `String` instances with `.equals` and you only need one `Scanner`, don't throw away two per loop iteration. Something like,

```
Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    String a = s1.nextLine();
    if (a.equals("END")) {
        break;
    }
    str1[count] = a;
    String b = s1.nextLine();
    if (b.equals("END")) {
        break;
    }
    str2[count] = b;
    count++;
    System.out.println("完成第" + count + "个依赖" + "  " + a + "->" + b);
}
```